# WinJS ListView placed into the Flyout or ContentDialog breaks after window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, winjs

I have a WinJS ListView placed into the WinJS Flyout.
It is being displayed fine until you change a window size AFTER showing this Flyout at least once. So if the flyout was shown and then you change window size - the ListView breaks and doesn't display items correctly, just their background.
Is there any solution for that?

HTML:

```
<div id="addRabbitFlyout" data-win-control="WinJS.UI.Flyout" aria-label="{Select a rabbit to add}">
    <div id='addRabbitListView' 
         data-win-control="WinJS.UI.ListView"
         data-win-options="{
         itemTemplate:  select('.rabbitTemplate'),
         layout: {type: WinJS.UI.ListLayout}
         }">
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.win-container {
    width: 200px;
}
.win-surface {
    width: 100%;
}
.win-item {
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.win-itembox {
    min-height: 40px;
}
.rabbitName {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your css rules?

Comment: There is no much of them. I've added them to the question.